# Python os.remove() fails to remove .doc file when another Microsoft Word document is open

Tags: python, .doc

I have function `process_candidate(filepath)` that can read text from 3 types of files .doc, .docx, .pdf. After reading, i need to remove the file. I used `os.remove(filepath)` to remove the file. The function works fine for .pdf and .docx. It works for .doc files too when there are no other MS Word document is opened. However, when I have a word document opened, I get a permission error for the .doc files alone.

**PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'c:\Users\123456\PycharmProjects\Documents\temp\sample_document.doc'**

I tried calling `os.chmod(filepath,0o777)` before `os.remove(filepath)`. But no luck
Below is my code

```
@app.route('/upload',methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload():
    candidates = []

    target = os.path.join(Config.APP_ROOT, 'temp')
    #print("target folder", target)

    if not os.path.isdir(target):
        os.mkdir(target)

    for file in request.files.getlist("file"):


        filename = file.filename
        destination = "\\".join([target,filename])

        file.save(destination)

        candidate = process_candidate(path=destination)
        candidates.append(candidate)

        os.chmod(destination,0o0777)
        os.remove(destination)  #this line throws error for .doc file only

     return render_template('completed.html', candidates=candidates)
```

My code to convert .doc to text is

```
def extract_txt_from_doc(filepath):
    if threading.currentThread().getName() != 'MainThread':
        pythoncom.CoInitialize()
        doc = win32com.client.GetObject(filepath)
        text = doc.Range().Text
        pythoncom.CoUninitialize()

    return text
```

Comment: Are you saving the file only to share it with some other process?

Comment: Do you have Word or some process looking at that file when you try to delete it?

Comment: @latish - I am saving the file so that the `process_candidate` function always looks into the same folder to process the file. Yes, I am saving to the folder only to share to the `process_candidate` function

Comment: @C.Nivs - No, as far as i looked, no other process is looking into the same file. What throws me off is how the same code works when there is no MS word document is kept open. I am sure I did not open the same file I am passing to this function.

Comment: @vinodhraj if that's the case, then you can use tempfile module which fits this use case. The thing is you can create temporary files which get deleted on f.close(). Please refer the docs https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/tempfile.html. Going by this way will avoid the problem you are facing